# Haskell debugging the GHCI / GHC

Tags: debugging, haskell, functional-programming

I'm interested in Compilers. 
And I'm trying to study and understand the implementation details of how the ghci / GHC (Haskell Interpreter / Compiler) performs lexing, parsing and execution of the code. so, I want to step through the ghci / ghc code, line by line.

I don't even know where to begin with that task. I have looked for how to debug haskell programs in general, I can't find anything interesting.

- How does one perform step by step debugging in Haskell ?
- How to step through the ghci ?

Comment: Try `:?` in GHCi to display all commands available.  You'll see a section on the debugging commands.

Comment: @bheklilr, ok. trying that right now.

Comment: @bheklilr, Thanks. By using ghci, I can successfully debug my program. but I can't dig into the GHC code itself.

Comment: If you're wanting to debug GHC code, you'll need the [source](https://github.com/ghc/ghc), and you'll need to be able to build it.  However, I think that your question isn't really appropriate for SO because it is very broad without a specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: my understanding is that since GHCI is an interpreter, I don't need to grab the sources in order to step through it. I thought I could type in an expression and start stepping through, just like what ruby allows you to do, I believe.

Comment: it's a little more complicated than that. Ghci compiles code on the fly with debugging symbols, but ghci itself is not sitting around as source code like the standard libs for python, it's already compiled without debugging symbols.

Comment: [This article](http://aosabook.org/en/ghc.html) may help. GHC itself is incredibly complex (> 100k lines of code) so I don't think it's useful going through it all.

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions.

I grabbed the source code of the ghc and built it.
I was able to locate the entry point of the compiler, which is ghc/Main.hs. However I can't start ghc/Main.hs from within the ghci window, I get error messages saying : 

"Could not find module 'GHC'. It is a member of the hidden package 'ghc-7.9.20141001'. Use -v to see a list of the files searched for."